# Adding to list indices

Tags: list, append

say I have a list:

```
x = [2, [2, 5, 6], 'car', 7]
```

I understand I can append to `x[1]` by using `x[1].append('hi')`
which gives:

```
x = [2, [2, 5, 6, 'hi'], 'car', 7]
```

How can I turn other index positions into their own lists so I can append.
At the moment I'm trying:

```
x[0].append('hi')
```

which gives this error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

The output I'm looking for would be:

```
x = [[2, 'hi'] , [2, 5, 6, 'hi'], 'car', 7]
```

Comment: Do you want to append `hi` just to the first 2 elements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a simple casting type:

```
x[0] = [x[0]]
x[0].append(...)
```